# Spring MVC Log4j - Linux

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, log4j

i am facing a problem for the last 2 days and i cant figure out no matter what !
i want to exprort the logs file from appenders to my home directory or somewhere else that i can find it, in windows is working perfect i can export it either in $catalina.home or with absolute path somewhere else , but in linux(ubuntu) i tried everything and not working at all , someone help me please

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="logs_info" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <!-- <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/Gps_Zero/Logs_Info.log" 
            /> -->
        <param name="file" value="/root/Desktop/log1.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" /> <!-- 2 times - files * 10 mb -->
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>

    </appender>

    <appender name="logs_error" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

        <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="file" value="/root/Desktop/log2.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" /> <!-- 2 times - files * 10 mb -->
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>

    </appender>



    <appender name="html" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">

        <param name="file" value="/root/Desktop/log3.html" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout">
            <param name="Title" value="Application log" />
            <param name="LocationInfo" value="true" />
        </layout>

    </appender>


    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="html" />
        <appender-ref ref="logs_info" />
        <appender-ref ref="logs_error" />
    </root>



    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>


    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="off" />
    </logger>












</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Did you see any error on console when you start app? May be file system access rights issue.

Comment: i deploy it in windows (war) with maven and then i open VPS(SSH-FTP) i transfer the war file into webapps folder and the i restart the tomcat7 service . you think may be file system access rights? how can i solve the issue ? create the files and chmod before i run the web app?

Comment: `chown` or `chmod` can solve file access issue. Is catalina.out file created somewhere for your app run? Look in there. If Tomcat can't write there, I believe it would try to write into console `stdout`. So try to look into Tomcat logs or capture it's output somehow.

Comment: Thnks a lot my friend !!!! i've changed the privileges of catalina.home directory to chmod 777 and  <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/log4j1.log" /> and Boom !! thnks !

Comment: I created answer, if you don't mind to give me some points :).

Answer (score 0):

Communication in comments showed that it is file access issue.

`chown` or `chmod` can solve file access issue. Look if catalina.out file is created somewhere for your app run. If yes, look in there.

If Tomcat can't write there, I believe it would try to write into console `stdout`. So try to look into Tomcat logs or capture its output somehow.